# Composer won't install due to strange syntax in composer.json: "package/package": "other-package as x.xx.x"

Tags: php, composer-php, phalcon

This composer.json file won't install due to an inline alias. This line appears to be the culprit:

`"jms/serializer": "xsd2php-dev as 0.18.0",`

I'm not sure what this is trying to do. Is it trying to *replace* the jms/serializer with xsd2php-dev at version 0.18.0?

Here is the full file:

```
{   
    "require": {
        "jsanc623/phpbenchtime": "dev-master",
        "gte451f/phalcon-json-api-package": "dev-master",
        "soundasleep/html2text": "~0.2",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~5.2",
        "php": ">=5.2.0",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "jms/serializer": "xsd2php-dev as 0.18.0",
        "robmorgan/phinx": "^0.5.3",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.19"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "codeception/codeception": "*",
        "flow/jsonpath": "dev-master",
        "goetas/xsd2php": "2.*@dev",
        "goetas/xsd-reader": "2.*@dev"
    },
    "repositories": [{
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/goetas/serializer.git"
    }]
}
```

Composer version 1.10.19

here is an example of my error I get:

```
$ composer
[UnexpectedValueException]
  
Invalid version string "xsd2php-dev" in "xsd2php-dev as 0.18.0", the alias source must be an exact version, if it is a branch name you should prefix it with dev-
```

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#require-inline-alias

Comment: What's your exact question here? The usage of aliases is well documented. If you state "doesn't seem to like it", is there any error message you could share?

Comment: @Jeto ah so this is an inline alias; so why would I be getting the above error?

Comment: @NicoHaase sorry, my real question is that composer won't install and I don't know why. it looks like it has to do with this inline alias (which I had assumed was incorrect syntax)

Comment: Try change it to `dev-xsd2php as 0.18.0` - non-version-like branches should be prefixed by `dev`, not suffixed.

Comment: that was it, @rob006, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per @rob006:

> Try change it to dev-xsd2php as 0.18.0 - non-version-like branches should be prefixed by dev, not suffixed.

`"jms/serializer": "xsd2php-dev as 0.18.0",`

to

`"jms/serializer": "dev-xsd2php as 0.18.0",`